# Parallel Speedup and Efficiency

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing

Just have a quick question.

What is the difference between a parallel speedup and efficiency.

Thanks

Comment: umm what? Can you please clarify your question, it is hard to tell what you're really asking.

Comment: Updated, just kept it simple for now.

Comment: Just have a quick question: Do you think we can't see what's homework and what is not?

Comment: Its not homework, i wanted to get a good understanding of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two workers, in a naive world, you should be able to finish a job in half the time. This is a 2x **speedup**. If the two workers do not interact at all and are working independently, a 2x speedup is theoretically possible. This class of problems are called [embarassingly-parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel), and aren't very common.
In this case both of the workers can continue working just as quickly as the original worker could i.e., **efficiency** is at 100%.

[Amdahl's Law:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) In real-world computing though, there are always some shared resources, and consequently some contention between the two workers. Which mean both workers will likely run a bit slower than the original single worker.

- *Efficiency* now becomes a measure of the drop in speed for each worker. Say they're running at 0.9 times the original single worker speed, the efficiency is now 90%
- The drop in efficiency also means in the original amount of time, either worker has only completed 90% of their job. So the actual speedup drop from 2x to 1.8x

Comment: So when efficiency drops, does this mean each worker is doing less work?

Comment: So lets say we want to achieve a good speedup with multithreading by splitting work onto multiple cores, a lower efficiency means it is more efficient as each core does not have to do so much work?

Comment: When efficiency drops, each worker is doing its work *slower*. Unrelated to efficiency, but they also do lesser total amount of work because the work is now split up between several workers.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding technical definitions here. Let *T_1* be the time required by your application to complete on 1 processor (sequential time) and *T_p* the time required by your application when executed on *p* cores. Then, the speedup S is defined as

*S = T_1 / T_p*

The speedup measures the acceleration you obtain when using *p* cores,
The corresponding efficiency E is defined as

*E = T_1 / (p T_p)*

The efficiency measures how well you are utilizing the *p* cores in parallel.
The maximum theoretical speedup on *p* cores is *p*, but you will attain this limit only for embarrassingly parallel apps (no communication and no other overheads). Correspondingly, the maximum efficiency is 1 (or 100%). In practice, a common rule of thumb is that an app should aim to achieve at least an efficiency of 0.7 (or 70%).

Answer (score 1):

One lady can have a baby in 9 months.

If you put 9 ladies on the case, you can't get a baby in 1 month. That's zero speedup and 11% efficiency.

If you put 9 ladies on the case, you can get 9 babies in 9 months. That is 9x speedup and 100% efficiency.